# paypal IPN notifyURL calls wrong url

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal standard payment done by HTML variables. I have set up IPN url  and turned it ON in my profile. 
url in profile : http://example.com/IPNHandler.aspx

But I got one more payment page where I need to create different IPN handler and called this URL in "notify_URL" from code.

```
redirecturl += "&notify_url = http://example.com/IPNHandler2.aspx"
```

As per the paypal documentation default url in profile gets overridden if we send the notify_url to the paypal. It was working fine till last month, but last month when I tried the second payment its IPN messages sent to first URL in the profile which is "http://example.com/IPNHandler.aspx". Seems "notify_URL" is not working anymore.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: I can confirm as well, IPN service stop sending notifications as of the last week Amazon debacle (and other big shots like GoDaddy, etc). I'm not sure if they are related or it's just a coincidence.

Also try to set your `notify_url` value without spaces around the = , ex: `notify_url=http://example.com/...`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Anyway I just fixed it by asking technical help from PayPal. And what they suggest is go to PayPal profile, change PayPal button language encoding to UTF-8. And Yes, as you said remove leading and trailing spaces in all parameters too.